# Setting a Starting Point from Point Shape in Graphical Modeler QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, network, qgis-network-analysis

I want to use a point Layer with 1 point as the input for the network-analysis in the graphical modeler of QGIS.
I tried extracting coordinates from geometry and lots of stuff in the field calculator but I cannot make it work.

Using a point as input and transforming it to a point layer is no option (sadly). Anyone has an idea what tool could help here?

Thanks a lot
[image]